# Create reusable GUI components in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I have a project using `Spring MVC` and I recently added the use of `Apache Tiles` on my pages. But I a `model Book` I have to display on a lot of different pages. Can I define a Book `GUI Component` somehow in `Spring`. I would like to have something like this:

A `GUI Component` I can define as such:
*book.viewcomponent*

```
<h1>${book.title}</h1>
<span>${book.summary}</span>
```

A first page using this component by passing a `model` object
*booklist.jsp*

```
<!--some import to let me insert with prefix:"insert"-->
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<insert page="book.jsp" model="${book}">
</body>
</html>
```

A second a page using this component by passing a `model` object
*morebooks.jsp*

```
<!--some import to let me insert with prefix:"insert"-->
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<insert page="book.jsp" model="${book}">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do this with includes or tags. With includes:

```
<!-- There's a book in the request -->
<jsp:include page="book.jsp" />
```

In this case, if you have things like `${book.title}` inside your book.jsp file, then there must be a Book object called "book" in the request prior to including your fragment.

With **tags**, it's a little more formal. You need to write your tag in a file, along with its parameters definition. The following would be your `book.tagx` tag inside, for example, `WEB-INF/tags/mytags`:

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.0">
  <jsp:directive.attribute name="book" type="your.package.Book" required="true" />
  <h1>${book.title}</h1>
  <span>${book.summary}</span>
</jsp:root>
```

You can then import this tag adding the namespace referring to the location where you saved it:

```
xmlns:mytags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/mytags"
```

and finally use it:

```
<mytags:book book="${book}" />
```

As you can see, here the parameter is passed to the tag, instead of being passed implicitly in the request.

More info on creating tags: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/6n5sg7b5m/index.html

Comment: Helpful, but a not very elegant solution. I would have to load the book.viewcomponent in the doTag() method and replace the values such as ${book.title} myself. Doesn't sound worth the trouble

Comment: Excuse me, I gave you the wrong link. I was referring to pure JSP tags instead of java code tags (the ones with the `doTag()` method). I've updated the answer with a more detailed explanation of how this tag would be. Hope that helps.